# cx_oracle giving wrong division output

Tags: python-2.7

I am currently using **Python 2.7.5** on **Aix 5.1** with `cx_Oracle` version 5.2 to connect to Oracle 12c

I am trying to execute a SQL query, and put its output in a csv file using the `csv` module. The query I am running is:

```
Select 1.563/100, 0.38/100 from dual;  - - simplified query
```

However the output in file is:

> 0.015629999999999998,0.0038

When I expect it to be

> 0.01563,0.0038

After doing some research, I believe this is because floating point numbers are represented in Binary Base 2.

But I don't know how to resolve this?

I also tried

```
from __future__ import division
```

But it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

function ROUND is your friend

```
SELECT ROUND(3.1415926,4),ROUND(3.1415926,5) FROM DUAL;

ROUND(3.1415926,4) ROUND(3.1415926,5)
------------------ ------------------
            3.1416            3.14159
```

or, in Python:

```
print round (3.1415926, 4)
print round (3.1415926, 5)

3.1416
3.14159
```

Comment: Mind you, the output of `round` is another binary floating-point number, which is also inaccurate, so the sure method is converting to string (with the desired precision) with functions like `sprintf` or `to_char` depending on the given language.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Zsigmond Lőrinczy. 
It worked, by using a to_char(round())

```
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> con = cx_Oracle.connect(xxx/xxx@xxx)
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select 1.563/100, round(1.563/100,5), to_char(round(1.563/100,5))           from dual")
>>> l_result = cur.fetchall()
>>> l_result
[(0.015629999999999998, 0.015629999999999998, '0.01563')]
```